# TypeError: _init_() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, class

So, I  was trying myself with classes the first time and I stumbled upon following error:

```
Bücher-Tutorials.py:, line 30, in Mensch:
    _init_(name="John", groesse="175cm", passwort="A", age="2")
TypeError: _init_() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Here is a snippet of the snippet of the source code:

````
{`class Mensch:
    def _init_(self, name, age, groesse, passwort):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.groesse = groesse
        self.passwort = passwort
        def gruessen(self):
            print("Hallo,ich heiße" + name)
        gruessen(self)
    _init_(name="John", self="ad", groesse="175cm", passwort="A",age="2")```}
````

I tried creating an argument called self that went about ike this:

self.self = self,but it didn't work.
Can anyone help me,I would be really thankful
thank you,bye!
Edit:It worked,thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In `Python` the function (or to better say `method`) `__init__` is a `[constructor][1]`, and if you want to call it for its class, you just have to do like this:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
MyObject = MyClass('name') # In this case the constructor is called
```

---

In Python classes, to get the `self` the function looks for the inizialized object:

```
MyObject = MyClass('name') # In MyClass.__init__ MyObject will be self
```

---

In your case you simply have to call your constructor this way:

```
MyObject = Mensch(name="John", self="ad", groesse="175cm", passwort="A",age="2")
```

Since the arguments in your `__init__` prototype are positionals...

```
def _init_(self, name, age, groesse, passwort) #Do you see they have a specific order?
```

...you can call the constructor this way:

```
MyObject = Mensch("John", '2', "175cm", "A")
```

## About classes

---

The "functions inside classes" are called instance's methods, in fact `MyObject` is "an instance of class `Mensch`.

You really shouldn't declare `gruessen` inside `__init__`, do this instead:

```
def __init__(self, ...):
    ...
    self.gruessen() #This is the proper way to call a method
def gruessen(self):
    print(f'Hallo,ich heiße {self.name}')
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the last line.

```
class Mensch:
    def __init__(self, name, age, groesse, passwort): # __init__ instead of _init_
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.groesse = groesse
        self.passwort = passwort
        self.gruessen()

    def gruessen(self):  # this method can now be called from outside and by __init__
        print("Hallo, ich heiße " + self.name)

Bob = Mensch(name="John", age="2", groesse="175cm", passwort="A")
```

Bob introduces himself after initialization and this will return:

```
Hallo, ich heiße John
```